# How to mimic the behavior of CMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER in an earlier version of cmake / ctest

Tags: testing, cmake, cross-compiling, ctest

The CMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER variable ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TEST_LAUNCHER.html#cmake-test-launcher)) is introduced in cmake 3.29. It seems to allow the functionality to run a test defined with CTest's `add_test` through some simulator or similar. I require this functionality as I build a RISC-V executable containing some tests, and I want to run it in the Spike RISC-V ISA simulator.

This variable is not implemented in earlier versions of CMake, so I wondered how this used to be done. I cannot update cmake on my server as it is not a personal one, so need to reproduce the behaviour otherwise.

Currently I do

```
        add_test(
            NAME "Test: ${executable}"
            COMMAND "${TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR} $<TARGET_FILE:${executable}>"
        )
```

where `TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR` is the path to spike and some arguments, set in a toolchain file. This results in the error

```
Could not find executable /home/.../tools/riscv-isa-sim/build/spike --isa=rv32gc /home/.../tools/riscv-pk/build/pk /home/..../projects/project/build/test/<executable>
```

However, if I run the above as a command, it works fine and runs through spike. It is like CTest is treating the entire `TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR` string as a single long command.

I got this far by trying to copy the `add_test` example usage:

```
add_test(NAME mytest
         COMMAND testDriver --config $<CONFIG>
                            --exe $<TARGET_FILE:myexe>)
```

How can I direct the tests to run in my simulator? I am on cmake 3.26.

Comment: A **quoted** string represents a **single argument** in the command line. If you want to pass separate arguments, then do not use quotes: `COMMAND ${TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR} $<TARGET_FILE:${executable}>`

Comment: Ah thank you. I believed I had tried this and indeed removing the quotes here did not immediately fix the problem, however the issue was with how I had defined TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR. I had done `set(TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR "${spike} --isa=rv32gc ${pk})"` but doing `set(TOOLCHAIN_TEST_SIMULATOR ${spike} "--isa=rv32gc" ${pk})` fixed it! :)